# Running functions and mongo queries in setTimeout on Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

On server side, I am trying to update a field on my Mongo collection by a callback function that is passed as a parameter to a `setTimeout` on Meteor. The idea is to create a function that runs every N seconds/minutes to clean the database;

It keeps saying that "Meteor coding must always run inside a Fiber"

This is what I got

```
function MyClass(){ //foo }

MyClass.prototype.interval = function(time,callback){
    var interval = function(time,callback){
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
            callback();
            interval(time,callback);
        },time);
    };

    interval(time,callback);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function (){
        new MyClass().interval(1000,function(){
            //foo
            mycol.update({field:{$lt:one_hour_ago}},{$set:{boolean:false}});
        });
    });
}
```

And it throws "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment."

I read some people talking about binding the callback to Fiber, but my app says Fiber isn't defined.

How can I make this work? How do I have to use bindEnvironment in my case?

Answer (score 3):

You must use `Meteor.setInterval` and `Meteor.setTimeout` instead.

See: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers